# Scriptural references for the 'Giloy ( गिलोय ) herb' being born from the Amṛta drops?

Tags: scripture, ayurveda, plants

Giloy / Giloe ( गिलोय ) is an important ayurvedic herb known for its myriad health-benefits, especially during these trying times of Covid-19 pandemic. It's also called Guduchi or Amṛtā (*Tinospora cordifolia*).

Now, in [this document](https://www.nmpb.nic.in/sites/default/files/Giloy_Book.pdf), (pdf page - 15), prepared by the Ministry of Ayush: GOI, it gives an origin story of the herb as follows:

> The Sanskrit and Hindi name Amrita is derived from the ancient Hindu scriptures where Amrit was used to bring the dead back to life and keep away from growing ill and old. ***Bhav-prakash Nighantu* provides mythological description about the origin of Guduchi/Amrita from the drops of the Divine Nectar (Amrita) which was sprinkled on the dead bodies of the monkeys to make them alive who died during the battle between Rama and Ravana. Few drops of the nectar from the bodies of the monkeys fell to the ground and them Guduchi (Giloy) sprouted.**

Now, for most parts, the story seems right as per scriptures where [Indra revives the dead army of Rāma after the great battle](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15431/resurrection-stories-in-hindu-scriptures/15440#15440). However, the last part pertaining to Giloy seems to lack scriptural backing. The document cited by the Ministry -  *Bhav-Prakash Nighantu* as source, however, it's at max an [ayurveda book](https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B5_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B6), and not a canonical theological text.

Question is - What are the canonical scriptural references (besides the *Bhav-Prakash* ) for the Giloy herb sprouting from the Amṛta drops?

Comment: Bhav Prakash itself is an authority on Ayurveda (which is an Upaveda). So what Bhav Prakash mentions is not required to be validated from other scriptures.

Comment: Actually, I don't want validation for the ayurveda treatise @Rickross, just want to know if similar versions exits elsewhere too. I have edited it .

Comment: Okay @Vivikta ..